# Regex gsub R differentiate between ellipsis and periods

Tags: regex, r, gsub

`text="stack overflow... is a popular website."`

I want to separate punctuation marks from words. The output should be:

`"stack overflow ... is a popular website . "`

Of course, the command `gsub("\\.", " \\. ", text, fixed = FALSE)` returns:

`"stack overflow .  .  .  is a popular website . "` because it does not differentiate between periods and ellipsis (suspension points). In short, when three periods are found together in the text, R should consider them as a single punctuation mark.

Comment: `gsub("(\\.+)", " \\1 ", text, fixed = FALSE)` does... (or `gsub("([[:punct:]]+)", " \\1 ", text, fixed = FALSE)` for any type of punctuation)

Comment: Only periods, what about other punctuation?

Comment: @stribizhev all punctuation marks should be separated from words, but ellipsis should be considered single entities, and not get separated in the process

Comment: `gsub("\\b([[:punct:]]+) ?"," \\1 ",text)` should do

Comment: but here in this question I am **only interested in separating periods and ellipses from words** (it is clear from the title I think)... The reason is that I have other commands that take care of the other punctuation marks, and that preserve intra-word dashes, apostrophes (I'd like) etc.

Comment: @Antoine Just in case you wish to manage a specific set of punctuation, handling cases on word boundaries, see [this](https://regex101.com/r/tM0lR6/1) (one pass for dots, coma, semi-colon, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a non-lookaround approach will be more efficient and readable:

```
text="stack overflow... is a popular website."
gsub("*[[:space:]]*(\\.+)[[:space:]]*", " \\1 ", text)
## => [1] "stack overflow ... is a popular website . "
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/j29XPF)

I updated the post since the space is required before and after the punctuation.

The `[[:space:]]*` around the `(\\.+)` match zero or more whitespace and the `(\\.+)` will match one or more periods. The `(...)` form a *capturing group* whose value is stored in a numbered buffer #1 that we can access using the `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern. So, `\1` is replaced with the periods captured by the pattern. Capturing is more efficient than using lookarounds since there is no overhead of checking text before/after the current position.

Now, **if you need to handle all punctuation**, use **`[[:punct:]]`**:

```
gsub("[[:space:]]*([[:punct:]]+)[[:space:]]*", " \\1 ", text)
```

See [R regex help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html):

> `[:punct:]`
>   *Punctuation characters*:
>   `` ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~. ``

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/ktj445):

```
text="Hi!stack overflow... is a popular website, I visit it every day."
gsub("[[:space:]]*([[:punct:]]+)[[:space:]]*", " \\1 ", text)
## => [1] "Hi ! stack overflow ... is a popular website , I visit it every day . "
```

## UPDATE FOR HYPHENATED WORDS

To avoid matching hyphenated words, you can match and *skip* the `-` that are surrounded with word boundaries:

```
text="Hi!stack-overflow... is a popular website, I visit it every day."
gsub("\\b-\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s*(\\p{P}+)\\s*", " \\1 ", text, perl=T)
## => [1] "Hi ! stack-overflow ... is a popular website , I visit it every day . "
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/mWnfWg)

Comment: @CathG: I wrote the same comment before you but removed it, and yours is not correct since the space is not where it  should be in the replacement pattern.

Comment: As you posted some comment on my solution, this is not showing space after the end `.` (I meant from looking at the OP's expected output)

Comment: Repeating myself as above (under Q), I would test the presence of a word boundary to avoid doubling an existing space, and use the punctuation character class and just replace the leading space if there's one.

Comment: I was kind of kidding anyway but I put space before and after the punctuation mark, I thought it was what OP wants. But it was just a comment,  to give a hint...

Comment: Now, it will add spaces around the punctuation. I think a TRE regex should work faster and is more "predictable".

Comment: I indeed would like space both before and after the ellipsis (so that `aaa...bbb` becomes `aaa ... bbb`)

Comment: @Antoine: My solution does that. Please check the demo.

Comment: @Antoine are you just looking after the dots, or a set of punctuation ?

Comment: @Tensibai All punctuation marks should end up separated from words, but I already have other commands that separate the other punctuation marks from the text actually... I was stuck for the ellipsis only

Comment: Last side note: please stop the ugly double backslash escaping when a character class would do the same: `[.]` it's far most readable IMO.

Comment: @stribizhev just for the sake of completeness, could you show how to turn `aaa...bbb` into `aaa ... bbb`. Right now it only works if `...` does not touch one of the two words, but not if it touches both. Thanks!

Comment: @Tensibai: `\\.` is exactly the same number of characters as in `[.]`. It is not ugly right here.\

Comment: @Antoine: The code I posted [handles `aaa...bbb`](https://ideone.com/fBAnOf). Also, here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM6pE4/1).

Comment: @stribizhev I agree here it's not that ugly :) was more a generic ask to stop finding regexps with a load of double backslashes. (upvoted now there's the whole punctuation handling :))

Comment: @stribizhev OK... I understand the confusion. Your code that handles **all punctuation** does take care of `aaa...bbb`, but not the initial one, in which I am interested because I have other commands that preserve intra-word dashes, inner apostrophes etc.

Comment: @stribizhev in short, if you could simply update the initial code `gsub("*[[:space:]]*(\\.+)[[:space:]]", " \\1 ", text)` so that it handles `aaa...bbb` that'd be it

Comment: @stribizhev and also it does not work for `"aaa..."`

Comment: @stribizhev try `gsub("*[[:space:]]*(\\.+)[[:space:]]", " \\1 ", "aaa...bbb")` or `gsub("*[[:space:]]*(\\.+)[[:space:]]", " \\1 ", "aaa...")`, you'll see that it does not work. I am only looking at your first proposition, not at the one that handles all punctuation, because my question is only about separating periods and ellipses from words (for the reason given in the comment below my question)

Comment: @Antoine: I am sorry, there is a typo - the `*` must be at the end of course. The code demo did not have the typo and worked correctly. I thought I did not forget that `*` - that is why I did not understand your comments. Today is the busiest day I have had in a year :(

Comment: @stribizhev no worries

Comment: @Tensibai: No problem :)

Answer (score 3):

After this load of comments this regex should be the most likely to fit your needs:

```
(?:\b| )([.,:;!]+)(?: |\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tM0lR6/4)

To use it in R the backslashes have to be doubled.

So we end up with:

```
text<-c('Hi!stack-overflow... is a popular website, I visit it every day.',
    'aaa...',
    'AAA...B"B"B',
    'AA .BBB #unlikely to happen but managed anyway')

> gsub('(?:\\b| )([.,:;!]+)(?: |\\b)',' \\1 ',text)
[1] "Hi ! stack-overflow ... is a popular website , I visit it every day . "
[2] "aaa ... "                                                              
[3] "AAA ... B\"B\"B"                                                       
[4] "AA . BBB #unlikely to happen but managed anyway"
```

Comment: Why use `(?:\b| )?`? What is your intent here?

Comment: To be sure we're between word boundaries or spaces, kind of extraneous test to avoid surrounding by spaces punctuation in smileys for example.

Comment: But [it does not prevent that](https://regex101.com/r/tM0lR6/2). The groups are optional. If you make them obligatory, that would work [like this](https://regex101.com/r/tM0lR6/3).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
gsub("(?<=\\.)$|(?<=\\w)(?=\\.)", " ", text, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "stack overflow ... is a popular website . "

gsub("(?<=\\.)$|(?<=\\w)(?=\\.)", " ", "aaa...", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "aaa ... "

gsub("(?<=\\.)(?=$|\\w)|(?<=\\w)(?=\\.)", " ", "aaa...bbb", perl=TRUE)
#[1] "aaa ... bbb"
```

Comment: Many thanks. That'd be great if you could briefly explain what the regex is telling.

Comment: This is probably not the most efficient regex for this task.

Comment: Ok, let's jump in, I guess there will be many edits to my post though.

Comment: @Antoine Will add some explanation.  Got taken away with finding faults in the other solution.