# regex R: add space between punctuation marks and words, but also between punctuation marks

Tags: regex, r, perl, gsub

The following command adds space between punctuation marks and words, but keeps the adjacent punctuation marks as a single block. This is alright for `...` (it should be considered a single unit), but not for the other symbols.

Input: `text = "blabla!??....balabla, bla;bla:"`

R command: `gsub("((?:\b| )?([.,:;!?]+)(?: |\b)?)", " \\1 ", text, perl=T)`

Output: `"blabla !??.... balabla ,  bla ; bla : "`

**Desired output**: `"blabla ! ? ? .... balabla ,  bla ; bla : "`

Comment: Maybe `[[:blank:]]*([.]{2,}|[.,:;!?])[[:blank:]]*` will do? Check [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX9rZ4/1).

Comment: `gsub("([!?;,:]|(\\.+))", " \\1 ", text)` should work (separating punctuation marks other than the point from the point)

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762973/regex-gsub-r-differentiate-between-ellipsis-and-periods) (Just saw it's a follow up)

Comment: @Tensibai: With all the previous OP questions in mind, I find this one rather unclear. Especially, what OP is up to in the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew indeed, what is the final goal is pretty unclear. Previous solution keeps punctuation together, OP's with to separate them...

Comment: @Antoine could you enlighten us about the the final goal of all this, and side question are multiples spaces acceptable between punctuation marks ? (I've more and more the feeling we're solving an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here as there's packages in R to do text analysis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Test data:** `text<-'bla  bla!??....bala bla, bla;bla:'`

I didn't find a way to avoid calling gsub twice, the most conservative seems to be:

```
gsub('(?<=[,:;!.?])  (?=[,:;!.?])',' ',gsub("([,:;!?]|[.]+)", " \\1 ", text),perl=T)
```

Which gives: `"bla  bla ! ? ? .... bala bla ,  bla ; bla : "`

I added spaces to the test data to ensure they're kept clean after processing.

On multiples lines for ease of reading:

```
gsub('(?<=[,:;!.?])  (?=[,:;!.?])', ' ', # replace 2 spaces surrounded by punctuation by only one space
     gsub(
        "([,:;!?]|[.]+)"," \\1 ", # replace punctuation by themselve surrounded by spaces
        text
     )
     ,perl=T
)
```

In the inner part we replace `??` by `?  ?` so we need to suppress this double space between the two punctuation marks, as we may not whish to do this anywhere in the text we have to ensure those 2 spaces are surrounded by punctuation marks we did replace before.

As the lookarounds are not part of standard R regexes, we need to use `perl=TRUE` on this outer `gsub`

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I don't use R, but think I can glean the syntax from the question. I played around with it in Perl 6 and came up with this...

```
my $text = "blabla!??....balabla, bla;bla:";
say $text.subst(/( '.' + | <:P> )/, {" $0 "}, :g);
# blabla !  ?  ?  .... balabla ,  bla ; bla :
```

So at a guess, I'd say you could do it R like this?

```
gsub("(\\.+|[[:punct:]])", " \\1 ", text)
```

What I'm doing is matching as many `.`'s in a row and spacing around them -OR- matching any punctuation and spacing around it. The `punct` should never match a dot because the first clause in the regex should catch it.

Comment: Ahhhhhh. Two things. I totally missed the fact that you wanted to keep the dots together... and I totally missed the fact that you were asking about R, since this was tagged in `perl`... SO I provided perl solutions. I should probably go ahead and delete this answer now.

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove all incorrect solutions.

Comment: I did edit to fix the R syntax, `fixed` is a parameter to tell gsub the pattern is fixed text and not a regex, so of no use here :). Drawback with [:punct:] is that is takes in consideration `-` (which OP does no wish from previous question).  As the Q was tagged perl, I assume it's ok to answer with perl only :) (But still, you end up with the same problem as me, the two spaces between the punctuation marks, which OP still have not clear if it's a problem or not...)

Comment: If 2 spaces is a problem for op, he can always split the resultant string on arbitrary whitespace, and then join with 1 space. Or gsub `\s+` with one space.